# Take inputs from multiple text-boxes and update the state to display all the username and passwords?

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a small app where I can collect a username and a password from user and display it from the updated state.

I am having problem in taking two inputs as "Username and Password" and create the state like wise. I want to create a object inside `this.state` like a associative array. How do I do it ?

I wrote my program like this, which will for now only takes the username. How do I associate the password also to it ?

```
import React from 'react';

export class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userName : ['john','sam','rob']
            password : ['123','abc','xyz']
        }
    }
    render(){
        const {userName} = this.state;
        return (
        <div>
        <h1>Happy Registering Here ...</h1>
        <div>
        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="password"/>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>

        <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>                
            <th>#</th>
            <th>userName</th>
            <th>password</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {
                userName.map((item, index) =>{
                    return (<tr key={item}>
                            <td>{index}</td>
                            <td>username</td>
                            <td>password</td>
                        </tr>)
                })

            }
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>


     </div>
    )
    } 
}
```

the output of my final app should be like a user enters two details , A username and a password. then i will display them below the text boxes as a list of Username and passwords like this..

```
No   username    password

0    john        123
1    sam         abc
2    rob         xyz
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
userName.map((item, index) =>{
                    return (<tr key={item}>
                            <td>{index}</td>
                            <td>{item}</td>
                            <td>{this.state.password[index]}</td>
                        </tr>)
                }, this)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to render both the username and password which you've included in your state object.

Below is an example  I've included on jsbin.

https://jsbin.com/gokamus/1/edit?html,js,output

As an overview, I've copied my changes below.

```
    const {userName} = this.state;
    const {password} = this.state;  
    ......

    <tbody>
        {
            userName.map((item, index) =>{
                return (<tr key={item}>
                        <td>{index}</td>
                        <td>{userName[index]}</td>
                        <td>{password[index]}</td>
                    </tr>)
            })

        }
    </tbody>
```

I do see a submit form which dynamically populates the **userName** and **password**. I haven't implemented it as from my understanding , the scope of this issue is to render both usernames and password correctly.